# How to embed notepad++ in a Windows Form application and how to control it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notepad++

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274; private const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 61488;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]

    public static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process proc;
        proc = Process.Start("Notepad++.exe");
        proc.WaitForInputIdle();          
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle,panel1.Handle);
        //SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
    }
}
```

When I execute `notepad.exe` instead of `notepad++.exe`, it works fine. Normal notepad comes inside the panel in the `Windows Form`. But when I use `notepad++.exe`, it is not seen inside the panel instead, is opened outside as a different window. I don't want this. My preference is `notepad++` to be embedded inside panel my `Windows Form`, through which, I want to control the `notepad++`.

Comment: I've tried your code, it works fine. Notepad++'s main window appears floating on the panel, not as separate window. I use latest version of Notepad++.

Comment: To Mad Sorcerer:::which version of notepad++ you use now?

Comment: do you really need notepad++ as it is, or just a [code editor](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Add Sleep after setParent it will work.

SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle,panel1.Handle);
Thread.Sleep(500)